# How To Limit Svn Access to VPN Users

Tags: networking, vpn, svn

We have a collection of subversion repositories on our server and want to get a VPN up and running so we can access them off site.

However, my boss insists that a select few repositories are not accessable unless you are actually in the office (or in the wireless outside...).

How can I achieve this?

My guess is to do something with the apache setup (we are using webdav)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [Order, Deny and Allow options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html). You should Allow from your local networks and deny from all. You'd use these config in a <Location> block for your repository url.

```
<Location /svn>
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    DAV svn
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /svn/secret>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Looks like its more of an apache question than subversion

Comment: Yeah, subversion is particularly dumb. It doesn't really have any concept of access control. That's done in apache (or svnserve)

Comment: Or particularly smart in that it leaves access and control to tools that are better suited to handling security and leaves itself to doing what it does well

Comment: I meant the tool was dumb, not the design :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache config just set the server. instead of setting it to *:80 make it something like 192.168.0.5:80 for only in office and for the vpn only use 10.0.0.5:80

This is how we have it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 10.0.0.100
        ServerAlias svn.domain.com
        <Location "/">
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath "/etc/subversion/repos"
                Require valid-user
                AuthType basic
                AuthName "Subversion Repository"
                AuthUserFile "/etc/subversion/repos/.user.passwd"
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: so I just create two svnroots? one for public and one for only office?

Comment: This won't work if the VPN user gets an IP address assigned from the same subnet as is the case with many end user VPN solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure this does what the asker wants.

Comment: I can set the VPN to have an ip range I like, the router should route it.